Three diagonals are concurrent in a hexagon with an angle condition.
This is a practice problem from Polish mathematician Waldemar Pompe as following:

A convex hexagon $ABCDEF$ with six equal sides satisfies the following condition:
$$
\angle A+\angle C+\angle E=\angle B+\angle D+\angle F.
$$
Show that three diagonal $AD,BE,DF$ are concurrent.
I would like to construct some triangles from this hexagon. But I totally have no clue. Hints or suggestions are appreciated.
I apologize that my original translation missed the important condition "all six sides are equal".

If the successive sides of a cyclic hexagon are a, b, c, d, e, f, then the three main diagonals intersect in a single point if and only if ace = bdf

see here

This is my silly mistake. I am sorry about it. The problem has a condition that all six sides are equal. I apologize that I missed this condition in Google translate.
